# Need help on a java assignment titled: Time Comparable

Tags: java

This is the assignment given:

For this assignment, you will be updating the Time class from Assignment 1. To get started, you can either make a copy of your Assignment 1 Time.java, or download the solution, Time.java.
First, you will need to update Time so that it implements the Comparable interface. This will require adding an implements statement to the class declaration as well as the compareTo method. Then, you will need to add a difference method to the class. These two methods' requirements are as follows:

```
   compareTo(Object other)
     //Returns -1 if current time is less than other.
        //Returns 0 if current time is equal to other.
        //Returns 1 if current time is greater than other.

String difference(Time t)
    //Returns a String holding the difference between the current time and 
    //the Time t passed in via parameter. All values should be positive, 
    //and in the format: 
    //Time difference: 08:09 
    //Time difference: 10:35
```

To test your code, download and run the runner class: student_runner_time.java. We will use a different, but similar, test class to grade the program. You will need to change the runner to test with other values to make sure your program fits all the requirements.

```
 Sample Run of student_runner_time.java:
    1712
    0945
    Greater than:
    1
    Less than:
    -1
    Times equal:
    0
    Hours equal:
    1
    -1
    Difference
    Time difference: 00:11
    Time difference: 00:11
    Time difference: 00:00
```

NOTE: You MUST use the class name "Time" for this assignment. REMEMBER: you must SUBMIT your answer. Your assignment doesn't count as complete unless it has been submitted.

This is what I submit:

```
public class Time implements Comparable<Time> {
  private int hour;
  private int minute;
  /*
Sets the default time to 12:00.
*/
  public Time() {
    this(12, 0);
  }
  /*
Sets hour to h and minute to m.
*/
  public Time(int h, int m) {
    hour = 0;
    minute = 0;
    if (h >= 1 && h <= 23)
      hour = h;
    if (m >= 1 && m <= 59)
      minute = m;
  }
  /*
Returns the time as a String of length 4 in the format: 0819.
*/
  public String toString() {
    String h = "";
    String m = "";
    if (hour < 10)
      h += "0";
    if (minute < 10)
      m += "0";
    h += hour;
    m += minute;
    return "" + h + "" + m;
  }
  public String difference(Time that) {
    int thisMin = this.hour * 60 + this.minute;
    int thatMin = that.hour * 60 + that.minute;
    int diffMin = Math.abs(thisMin - thatMin);
    int diffH = diffMin / 60;
    int diffM = diffMin % 60;
    String h = "";
    String m = "";
    if (diffH < 10) {
      h += "0";
    }
    if (diffM < 10) {
      m += "0";
    }
    h += diffH;
    m += diffM;
    return h + ":" + m;
  }
  @Override
  public int compareTo(Time that) {
    int thisMin = this.hour * 60 + this.minute;
    int thatMin = that.hour * 60 + that.minute;
    if (thisMin < thatMin) {
      return -1;
    } else if (thisMin > thatMin) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

These are the errors I received:

Your code has been evaluated against a set of test data.
You had 3 out of 7 tests pass correctly.
Your score is 42%.

The tests that failed were:

```
Test2: difference()
    Incorrect: First Time Less
    Incorrect: First Time Greater
    Incorrect: Large Difference
    Incorrect: Small Difference
```

Comment: so debug it and see what is wrong

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: Can you tell by looking at student_runner_time.java what values are being passed in as the times, in the failing tests?